Issue with ollama in google colab - TCP address already in use
I'm trying to run the following code:
!pip install colab-xterm
%load_ext colabxterm

Then I run %xterm so I can first download and then serve ollama & pull llama3 within %xterm:
curl -fsSL https://ollama.com/install.sh | sh
ollama serve & ollama pull llama3

This code was working fine during several tests, but now I'm running into an issue where the following error message appears:
Error: could not connect to ollama app, is it running?
Alternatively, when I try to run just ollama serve then I run into this issue:
Error: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:11434: bind: address already in use
I tried to force ollama to use a different port, but couldn't get that to work in colab. Anyone have any idea how I might solve this issue?

do you have ollama installed locally?

No, i'm trying to pull it and run it directly in colab. It was working fine a couple of days ago, but now I keep running into various errors.

try relaunching ollama on your computer.
